# Inconsistent messaging about Multiverse repo

Tags: updates, security, multiverse

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contains: *please note that software in multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security team*.

The [UpdateProcedures](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures) wiki contains: *The Ubuntu Security team also tracks issues in universe and multiverse and at their discretion...*

Which one is true?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like they *can* review/update packages, but *won't necessarily do so*.

Comment: The messaging does not seem inconsistent to me; both can be true. Multiverse users should indeed count upon NO support from the Ubuntu Security Team; if they receive a couple patches from that team, consider it a pleasant bonus. Note that Multiverse is generally non-free software, so patching it involves all kinds of headaches (like access to the source, copyright, licensing) generally best left to the *owner* of the software.

Comment: How is the messaging consistent? One says "WILL NOT" and the other says "tracks issues". Either they do or they don't.

Comment: You seem to be torturing one clause of that sentence to have a meaning that was clearly not intended by the author. Back up and look at the meaning of the entire sentence. And "tracks issues" is not a promise to provide support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording is not inconsistent or in conflict.

"tracks issues" means the Security team sees security bugs filed against packages, and tracks CVEs.  However, the Security Team may *track* the information, but are not obligated to update anything that is in Universe or Multiverse (which is why it says "WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security team" on a regular basis unless a community member steps up and works with the security team to prep the patches and release them in the way the Security team wants).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. So how many packages with security flaws are in multiverse without Ubuntu or Canonical doing anything about that? Is multiverse a mass of malware? Why is it enabled by default?

Comment: i think you misunderstand how packages get into Ubuntu.  MOST of the packages pass through Debian first.  Multiverse is a unique pocket in that it contains non-FOSS code/packages, it's not like it's "malware" laden, it's got picky restricted upload rights and who can upload to it.  Packages in Multiverse are not FOSS and for legal reasons can't ship by default.  Multiverse is also not enabled by default.  Universe is enabled by default, but again as most of the packages originate in Debian and they do extra scrutiny on packages in teh repos, there's not 'malware' in those repos.

Comment: if you FIND malware in a package in anywhere in the repositories reach out to the Ubuntu Security Team immediately and they can hunt/nuke/destroy the malware.

Comment: as for "security flaws", define "security flaws" and understand that Canonical and Ubuntu's security team is *small* and not able to look at everything.

Comment: The average user will not see any warnings or know what to do.

Comment: @AcceptableName I'm not talking about the 'average user' - and the average user won't have Multiverse enabled anyways.  They'll have restricted enabled (for drivers, etc. or such) but usually not Multiverse.

Comment: I went and installed the 22.04 desktop from a clean ISO and immediately checked sources.list and saw that multverse was enabled so your statement "the average user won't have Multiverse enabled" did not hold up to fact checking. Most anyone can try it and see that I'm right if they doubt me.

Comment: @AcceptableName you're right it's enabled (this has changed from the last time I checked), but **nothing is installed from it by default** - the average user isn't going to be randomly installing packages that're going to be in Multiverse, because they can't be installed by default because of legal reasons.  This doesn't mean they're *security* risks, but it does mean that the average user isn't going to have to *care* about Multiverse unless they're installing packages *from* multiverse (nor are they malware or security-risk-laden such that the average user will be hacked from use)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137417/discussion-between-acceptable-name-and-thomas-ward).

Comment: Comments have been locked here because, in chat, you immediately accused a moderator of lying and stating that 'there's no risk' - no, the risk is 'low'.  Any further comments on this answer serve only, based on OP's behavior, to draw argument or offtopic discusisons, so I have frozen the 'chat' room and locked comments on this post.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas said, both are true; the security team does track issues in the `multiverse` pocket but [our ability to provide fixes for issues in the `multiverse` pocket is very limited](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Multiverse).

If this worries you, please feel free to disable the `multiverse` pocket in your apt sources. I *love* the `manpages-posix` and `manpages-posix-dev` so I usually enable it myself -- but what you choose to run is entirely up to you.

If you want to see a list of what's in multiverse without enabling it yourself, the following should help:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release -cs)/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
unxz Packages.xz 
grep '^Package: ' Packages
```

Comment: Disclosure: sarnold is a member of the Ubuntu Security Team, paid by Canonical for that duty.  His words stand as the authoritative reference and answer.